# Deleting one or all Assets from a fieldusing a front end form

Tags: craft3, assets, form, assets-field

Good afternoon All,

Im trying to setup the ability for users to delete 1 or more of their own images from a multi photo asset field and have got stuck.

This is what is have so far,  I assumed adding a blank value would remove the asset in question

```
{% set images = myAssetQuery.all() %}

{% for image in images %}
    <span><img src="{{ image.getUrl('listingthumb') }}" alt="{{ image.title }}"></span>

    <input type="checkbox" name="fields[businessStandardImages][]" value="" />

{% endfor %}
```

Any help would be greatfully received

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are on a [front end entry form](https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/entry-form) editing an entry, there are a few steps to this.

First get all assets a user can choose from:

```twig
{% set allImages = myAssetQuery.all() %}
```

Next, get the ids of already chosen assets:

```twig
{% set alreadyChosenImages = entry.businessStandardImages.ids() %}
```

Loop over all images, check the ones already selected:

```twig
{% for image in allImages %}
<div>
    <label>{{ image.title }}
        {{ input(
            'checkbox',
            'fields[businessStandardImages][]',
            image.id,
            { checked: image.id in alreadyChosenImages }
        ) }}
    </label>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Altogether:

```twig
{# Get all possible assets #}
{% set allImages = myAssetQuery.all() %}

{# Get the currently related asset IDs #}
{% set alreadyChosenImages = entry is defined
    ? entry.businessStandardImages.ids()
    : [] %}

{# Loop over images and check any already selected ones #}
{% for image in allImages %}
<div>
    <label>{{ image.title }}
        {{ input(
            'checkbox',
            'fields[businessStandardImages][]',
            image.id,
            { checked: image.id in alreadyChosenImages }
        ) }}
    </label>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

There is also [a complete example in the documentation](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/assets-fields.html#saving-assets-fields).